# How to randomly add 1s to each row of a matrix in an incremental order

Tags: r, function, matrix

I have a matrix filled with 0s, as follows:

```
mat<-matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=10)
```

I'd like to randomly add 1s to this matrix, but in an incremental order i.e.

- row 1 gets a random 1
- row 2 gets 2 random 1s
- row 3 gets 3 random 1s and so on

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Dan

Comment: `for (i in 1:nrow(mat)) mat[i, sample(1:ncol(mat), i)] <- 1 `

Comment: `replace(mat, do.call(rbind, lapply(1:10, function(i) cbind(i, sample(1:10, i)))), 1)`

Comment: Thanks, both these work for me